# Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f81fe558fa0>": "Post.author" must be a "UserData" instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write simple tests for some endpoints but the second one keeps failing. Here's the test.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIRequestFactory, APIClient
from rest_framework import status
from django.urls import reverse
from .views import PostViewSet
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class PostListCreateTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.view = PostViewSet.as_view({"get": "list", "post": "create"})
        self.url = reverse("post_list")
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            email="testuser@gmail.com", name="testuser"
        )
        self.user.set_password("pass")
        self.user.save()

    def test_list_posts(self):
        request = self.factory.get(self.url)
        response = self.view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_create_post(self):
        print(User)
        print(self.user)
        client = APIClient()
        login = client.login(email="testuser@gmail.com", password="pass")
        self.assertTrue(login)
        sample_post = {
            "title": "sample title",
            "body": "sample body",
        }
        request = self.factory.post(self.url, sample_post)
        request.user = self.user
        print(isinstance(request.user, get_user_model()))
        response = self.view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And here's the view:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return posts

    def get_object(self):
        post = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, post)
        return post

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            post = Post.objects.create(
                title=request.data.get("title"),
                body=request.data.get("body"),
                author=request.user,
            )
            post = PostSerializer(post)
            return Response(post.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
            return Response(str(ex), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(
            data=dict(posts=serializer.data, total=len(serializer.data)),
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

And here's what I get:

> Found 2 test(s). Creating test database for alias 'default'... System
> check identified no issues (0 silenced). <class
> 'account.models.UserData'> testuser True Cannot assign
> "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f81fe558fa0>":
> "Post.author" must be a "UserData" instance. F.
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_create_post (posts.tests.PostListCreateTestCase)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/amr/Snakat/social_network/posts/tests.py", line 41, in
> test_create_post
> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED) AssertionError: 400 != 201
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 2 tests in 0.887s
>
> FAILED (failures=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Comment: Its probably because you are using the application without login, so "request.user" will return AnonymousUser and you can't use it for foreignkey author (Author must be user from your user model). If you want to avoid this error please add in exception handling or create the post while being logged in

Comment: @UsamaSaeed how to create the post while being logged in (from inside the test case)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you for test cases. If this is issue is related to test cases then please update the question description to be more clear so others can help you in that regard